# Updating a query in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Activity Code

```
String MMS = "(SELECT Name FROM UserData WHERE MessagesSent=(SELECT max(MessagesSent) FROM UserData))";
db.execSQL("UPDATE MainData SET MostMessagesSent = "+ MMS + "+ WHERE Data = MyData");
```

Im not sure about the code but this is is the onCreate of an activity... WIll the changes take place using this code?

Is it the correct method?

I hope the query is understandable...

Error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Settings.UsageSettings.onCreateView(UsageSettings.java:43)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

Comment: To know if the changes will take place, just try...

Comment: Im not sure how to... Because i cant add a toast or a Log statement for such code @StephaneM

Comment: just run this query and check your table's content is updated or not

Comment: I'm not sure wether this command `UPDATE MainData SET MostMessagesSent = (SELECT Name FROM UserData WHERE MessagesSent=(SELECT max(MessagesSent) FROM UserData)) WHERE Data = MyData` would run or not. Test it in SQLiteBrowser or any tool able to run queries and commands against SQLite

Answer (score 0):

If `db` is properly initialized, with this line:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE MainData SET MostMessagesSent = "+ MMS + "+ WHERE Data = MyData");
```

you want to execute an `UPDATE` statement that will update the column `MostMessagesSent` of table `MainData` with a value fetched from the query strored in the variable `MMS`:

```
String MMS = "(SELECT Name FROM UserData WHERE MessagesSent=(SELECT max(MessagesSent) FROM UserData))";
```

In order for this to work you must have initialized properly the `db` object.  
I suppose you have a class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` which provides the initialization of `db`.  
Also the names of the tables and columns must match the intended behavior.  
The problem is that `execSQL()` does not return a value indicating that the update was successful or not. 
You have to check it yourself.

Comment: I got an error... look to the edited question please

Comment: @NikkiZepher is `db` initialized properly? I can't say without your code.

Comment: i have just declared db; What should be its value?

Comment: @NikkiZepher what do you mean *just declared*? Do you have a class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`? If you do post its code and the code of the initialization of `db`. If you don't have such a class then you can't access an sqlite database.

Comment: i do have a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper but there is no method in there for updating table... i have a method for fetching data and adding data but not for updating so can u please get me the method code for updating?

Comment: If you have a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper and you initialize `db` properly then your code should work. Post the code that initializes `db` and the class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: is a method in Helper compulsory or u can achieve it using my method directly

Comment: Before db.execSQL(..) you must have initialized `db` but you haven't and this is why it returns null. I don't know why the initialization failed because I don't have your code.