# update method returning null

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

With the following code

```
SQLiteDatabase db;

MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity());

String MMS = "(SELECT Name FROM UserData WHERE MessagesSent=(SELECT max(MessagesSent) FROM UserData))";
Log.d("Tager", MMS);
db.execSQL("UPDATE MainData SET MostMessagesSent = "+ MMS + " WHERE Data = MyData");
```

I'm getting error at db.execSQL line... someone told me it's because of not initialising db but what else should I do?

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Settings.UsageSettings.onCreateView(UsageSettings.java:44)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  My first guess is that the problem is a syntax error caused by munging parameters into a query string.  That is just a really bad practice.  You might have other problems as well.

Comment: `db` is null, because you never assign it, at least not in the given code. Should you be getting that `SQLiteDatabase` from `MainData`?

Comment: Which field type of 'MostMessagesSent' 
If its text then you want to do like '"+ MMS + "'.
And first check MainData table any row is available or not?

Comment: You post the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320872/updating-a-query-in-sqlite again, yet still no code. Where is your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the `SQLiteDatabase` first see [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.io.File,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory))